# what is the use of icon file in vs 2008

Tags: .net, icons

Hi can anyone explain me how the icon file is used in vs 2008. what are the advantages of using it?
Please let me know if using icon helps the code in any manner..

Thanks in advance...
karthik

Comment: Are you asking whether including an icon to click on in Explorer changes your program at all?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2008 (actually all versions of Visual Studio), you have the option of adding an icon to your project.  Every executable is given a default icon to be used in the taskbar and as the icon for the exe file.  However, it is a very plain icon.  You can change this icon by changing your project icon.  This is purely a aesthetics change.  It has no impact on your code.  You can also assign an icon to each form in a Winforms or WPF application.  This allows you to further visually improve your application but again there is no impact on the code.